# Openstack Swift - Trying to download a blob using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problems downloading and saving locally the content of a blob from a container through the browser. Uploading a blob to a container worked properly but I can't download it using Firefox or Chrome. The only thing I achieved was retrieving the content in the reponse (Firefox) and I could download it only because of the Chrome cache (that is not valid for me). This is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFile() {
    var token = 'AUTH_AAAAAAAA';
    var method = 'GET';
    var url = 'http://ip/v1/AUTH_account/containerName/blobName';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/octet-stream');
    xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

I cannot just use

```
<a  href='http://ip/v1/AUTH_account/containerName/blobName' onclick='javascript:uploadFile();'>Blob to download</a>
```

because this link needs the Auth Token and it would respond with a "401 Unauthorized" message.

Thanks for your help.